# Почему не проходит итерация по Set?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Почему не отрабатывает цикл?

```
socket.on("disconnecting", () => {
 
    console.log(socket.rooms)
    for (let room of socket.rooms) {
        console.log("offline"+room)
    }
    console.log("end discont")

});
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Set(4) {
  'u1f8J9dpwHhAS-RFAAAD',
  'welcome',
  'test1',
  'worker_room�❤�'
}
end discont
```

Comment: Это в браузере? А выведите socket.rooms.size

Comment: 4 (это на сервере), если написать  `for (let room of Array.from(socket.rooms))` или 
           `socket.rooms.forEach((room:string)=>{
            console.log("line"+room)}
        )` всё работает

Comment: Нашёл ответ! Я использую ts, в конфиге версия языка: es5, поменял на es2015 и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вы не договариваете

```js
const rooms = new Set();
rooms.add('u1f8J9dpwHhAS-RFAAAD');
rooms.add('welcome');
rooms.add('test1');
rooms.add('worker_room�❤�');

console.log(rooms);
for (let room of rooms) {
  console.log(room);
}
```